# Installing Linux on HP Laptop

Tags: linux, windows-10, hp-pavilion, elementaryos

I am having a tough time on how to install Linux on my HP laptop and dual boot it.

So this is what I did:

1. I downloaded elementary OS to usb stick using Rufus. I followed the ubuntu guide
2. I know we need to know to some windows partitioning which I am frankly clueless. I will attach a screenshot on my current configuration.

[image: windows partition]

3. Tried going to Bios and go to system configuration and I am not sure which one should I choose.

[image: Bios]

I am not sure if I am missing anything.

Please help because frankly I am very lost.

Comment: What do you mean by 2? Do you have an empty partition? Did you try to boot from your USB thumb drive?

Comment: Yes, currently I manage to install elementary OS, and it even prompt me to restart my pc. So I took out the USB and restarted it but it took me straight to Windows instead of loading the GNUB menu where we can choose which OS we want to use

Comment: What drive did you install it to? You might have to mark a different drive as bootable. As your biggest partitions are NTFS it looks like you have installed Windows twice or have a data partition used by Windows?

Comment: @seth I got it working already. Just had to turn the boot option to Ubuntu and it worked fine. Thanks though for your help :)